# clean old array disks

Tags: 16.04, raid, mdadm

I installed a new version of ubuntu using some old disks.  In the setup they were configured as a raid so I let them go.

I am getting an error when mounting

```
pbrink@groot:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/md1 /mnt/test/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/md1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

So I am just wiping them and trying to start over

I stopped the raid

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --remove /dev/md0
```

then i try
`sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd`
but i get this error

```
mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/sdd
```

I decided to remove the partition on the drive using fdisk.  I checked for any partitions using parted.

```
pbrink@groot:/mnt$ sudo parted /dev/sdd print
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags
```

No partitions so I continue and make the raid

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdg /dev/sdh /dev/sdd
```

which gives me this error (Grabbed only the bad line for /dev/sdd

```
mdadm: /dev/sdd appears to be part of a raid array:
   level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdd but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
```

And asks if I want to continue.  This is on all 3 drives.  If I continue then I its like started from the top again.

QUESTION:

I have been googling all morning and no idea how to fix it.  I dont care about any data.  If the easy thing to do is wipe and start over I would but thats what im trying to do and its not working.  How can I make this raid with ext4 filesystem.

Comment: Is `/dev/md1` a typo or did you pass that to the `mount`command? In the following commands you use `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1`... Why does the `mount`try NTFS as filesystem for `/dev/md1`? After creating new raid `/dev/md1`, can you run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/md1`?

Comment: i think i must have missed that step.  trying it now after creating raid